# Combine two variables into one

Tags: php, variables

I try to merge or combine two variables into one new variable.

My Snippet looks like this:

```
<?php
  $text_headline = "dat headline";

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $text_text; $i++) {

    echo '$text_headline.$i';
  }
?>
```

But this didn't work, of course.

I also tried

```
$text_headline_combo = {$text_headline.$i};
```

But doesn't work as well. It sends me an error message.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /...

Does anybody have other solution for me?  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the intent for you to echo out "dat headline1", "dat headline2", etc?  Or is $i supposed to contain words?

Comment: Sorry forgot my target.
My target is to combine these 2 vars to get automaticly a new var. -> $text_headline1

In $text_headline1 is the real content that be return in echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, you have a series of headlines like

```
$text_headline1 = 'Some headline';
$text_headline2 = 'Another headline';
```

You want to output them in your loop.  You can use a double `$`

```
<?php
  $text_headline1 = 'Some headline';
  $text_headline2 = 'Another headline';

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $text_text; $i++) {

    $headlineVar = 'text_headline' . $i;
    echo $$headlineVar;
  }
?>
```

This is called [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: The period is the concatanation operator in php, but when used inside quotes becomes the normal period/full stop. Also, consider using single quotes everywhere for strings because they signify to the php parser that it doesn't have to examine the string for variables that may be contained inside it, hence they're faster for the majority of cases. Even in this example, I believe `$headlineVar = 'text_headline' . $i;` will be much easier to read in a few months time!

Answer (score 4):

String interpolation is only recognized in double quotes.

Try

```
echo "$text_headline.$i";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$text_headline .= $i;
```

The `.=` is called a concatenating assignment operator and it appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you need:

```
<?php
  $text_headline = "dat headline";

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $text_text; $i++) {
     $text_headline .= $i;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quotes on your echo line with double quotes.
Double quotes parse variables, single quotes do not.

Answer (score 0):

As Austin mentioned, you need to use double quotes for string interpolation such as 
`"$text_1.$text_2"`. Personally I like to separate out my strings as such `"string 1" . "string 2"` so that the code is easier to read.

It is also useful to use the `.=` operator. ex. `$text_1 .= $text_to_add;`